# Backbone: Easiest way to maintain reference to 'this' for a Model inside callbacks

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, this, underscore.js

```
var JavascriptHelper = Backbone.Model.extend("JavascriptHelper",
        {}, // never initialized as an instance
        {
            myFn: function() {
                $('.selector').live('click', function() {
                    this.anotherFn(); // FAIL!
                });
            },

            anotherFn: function() {
                alert('This is never called from myFn()');
            }
        }
    );
```

The usual `_.bindAll(this, ...)` approach won't work here because I am never initializing this model as an instance. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Regardless of Backbone's inner workings (which I'm unfamiliar with), `this.anotherFn()` is not going to refer to the object that has the .myFn and .anotherFn props, but to the DOM element jQuery passes to your event handler. Try `var that = this;` at the myFn level (outside the handler function you're passing to jQuery's .live) and then use `that.anotherFn()` inside the handler, and that should work (unless Backbone explicitly binds your extended object to something else, which would be unfortunate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it by hand:

```
myFn: function() {
    $('.selector').live('click', function() {
        JavascriptHelper.anotherFn();
    });
}
```

Or, if `anotherFn` doesn't care what `this` is when it is called (or if it wants `this` to be what `live` uses):

```
myFn: function() {
    $('.selector').live('click', JavascriptHelper.anotherFn);
}
```

As an aside, [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) has been deprecated in favor of [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/). Also, if you're not instantiating your JavascriptHelper, then why is it a Backbone.Model at all? Why not use a simple object literal:

```
var JavascriptHelper = {
    myFn: function() {
        //...
    },
    anotherFn: function() {
        //...
    }
};
```

And what are you expecting this construct:

```
var JavascriptHelper = Backbone.Model.extend(string, {}, {...})
```

to leave you in `JavascriptHelper`? Extending a string is strange but passing three arguments to `Backbone.Model.extend` is pointless, [it only cares about two arguments](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L1293). If you want static properties then you should be passing them as [the *second* argument](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-extend):

```
var JavascriptHelper = Backbone.Model.extend({}, { myFn: ... });
```

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, I'm actually using Parse but didn't want to confuse people so I changed it to Backbone.Model from Parse.Object so people would understand more easily (Parse is an extension of Backbone). Great advice! I'm changing all of my helpers to object literals. Thanks a lot!